# Using ffmpeg filter to change skin tone

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a ruddy face.  In my webcam the tone comes across pink.  Is there any filter already made that could help me correct this?

Answer (score 2):

The [`selectivecolor`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#selectivecolor-1) filter can be used for this purpose.

If you have a problem with pink color, you might want to adjust the reds primarily:

```
selectivecolor=reds=.5 -0.5 .5 -0.3
```

You can also tweak the filter with Photoshop, using the Selective Color adjustment:

[image]

Here, you can save the preset as an `asv` file and load that in the filter instead of manually specifying the parameters in the ffmpeg filter options.

Comment: Hi slhck!  This looks GREAT!  Thank you!